# Is 1,147 cM match for half sibling or cousin

Tags: autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis, half-siblings

I have an 855 cM match with a mystery 1st-2nd cousin.  My cousin has an 1,147 cM match to the same mystery cousin.

Is it possible the 1,147 cM match could be a half sibling?

Answer (score 1):

According to [DNAPainter](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/), the range for half-siblings is 1160-2436cM. So I would be doubtful that an 1147cM would be a half-sibling.